# Array of Form Control into a Dynamic FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm creating a dynamic form that uses a json response from a backend to render a Reactive Form.

So an example of the json response is this...

```
  "controls": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "value": "",
      "type": "text",
      "validators": {
        "required": true,
        "minLength": 4
      }
    },
 ]
}
```

And then the ts file builds the formGroup using formBuilder. I'm however having issues adding an array of formControl checkboxes... where one of the checkboxes MUST be checked or the form would be invalid. So the json looks like...

```
{
    "controls": [
        {
            "title": "Which of these items do you want to buy? Check as many as you'd like",
            "name": "items",
            "checkboxOptions": [
              {
                "value": "",
                "label": "Item 1",
                "name": "item1"
              },
              {
                "value": "",
                "label": "Item 2",
                "name": "item2"
              }
            ],
            "type": "checkboxgroup",
            "validators": {
                 "required": true
             }
          }
    ]
}
```

I can successfully add the checkboxgroup as it's own form group that has an array of form controls. I can then add that formGroup to the parent formGroup... but I'm having issues with the html part of the nested formGroup.

Btw... this is what the rendering of the textbox would look like

```
<form [formGroup]='myForm' (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" novalidate>
        <div *ngFor='let control of formControl.controls'>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>{{ control.label }}</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [formControlName]='control.name' [type]='control.type'>
                     
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
</form>
```

but I'm not sure how I'd render the array of formControl checkboxes with it's own validator.
Thanks

Comment: As you're using material angular, Really you needn't a FormArray to manange a checkboxgroup. a [mat-select multiple](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) return an array with the element selected or an empty array if no selected items, so a simple FormControl with Validators.required is enought. Yes a FormControl can store an array.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not looking for a dropdown of checkboxes.. but a group of checkboxes instead. That's sort of the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a component that mannage a FormControl that store an array.

Some like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-checkbox-group',
  template: `
  <span [class.horizontal]="horizontal">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list">
        <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="control.value && 
                         control.value.indexOf(item.value)>=0"
                      (ngModelChange)="update($event,item.value)">
          {{item.text}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
 
  `,
  styles: [
    `
   ul{
     padding:0;
     list-style: none;
    }
    .horizontal li{
      display:inline-block;
      margin-right:.5rem;
      
    }
    
    `,
  ],
})
export class CheckboxGroup {
  list: { value: string | number; text: string }[];
  control: FormControl;
  keys: any;
  log: any;
  horizontal:boolean

  constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('horizontal') _horizontal:any){
    this.horizontal=_horizontal!==undefined && _horizontal!==null?
              _horizontal!=="false":false
  }
  @Input('control') set _control(value: any) {
    this.control = value as FormControl;
  }
  @Input('source') set _source(value: any[]) {
    const type = typeof value[0];
    if (type == 'string' || type == 'number')
      this.list = value.map((x) => ({ value: x, text: '' + x }));
    else {
      const match = [
        ...JSON.stringify(value[0])
          .replace(/\"/g, '')
          .matchAll(/(\w+)\:[^,]*/g),
      ].map((x) => x[1]);
      this.list = value.map((x) => ({ value: x[match[0]], text: x[match[1]] }));
    }
  }
  update(checked: boolean, value: string | number) {
    const oldValue = this.control.value || [];
    if (!checked)
      this.control.setValue(
        oldValue.filter((x: string | number) => x != value)
      );
    else
      this.control.setValue(
        this.list
          .filter(
            (x: any) => x.value == value || oldValue.indexOf(x.value) >= 0
          )
          .map((x) => x.value)
      );
  }
}
```

Allow you write

```
<mat-checkbox-group [source]="control.checkboxOptions" 
    [control]="myform.get(control.name)" >
</mat-checkbox-group>
```

Be carefull, the component allow as "source" an array of string, an array of numbers of an array of object. The first property is the value, the second one the label of the checkbox

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz8ebz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-group.ts)

**Update** we can avoid create a new component, but in this case our .html is like

```
  <div *ngFor="let control of controlsJson?.controls">
      <div class="form-title">{{ control.title }}</div>

      <div class="bottom-space" *ngIf="control.type === 'checkboxgroup'">
        <ng-container *ngIf="dynamicForm.get(control.name) as ctrl">
          <div *ngFor="let item of control.checkboxOptions">
            <mat-checkbox
              [ngModel]="ctrl.value && ctrl.value.indexOf(item.value) >= 0"
              (ngModelChange)="
                update($event, item.value, control.checkboxOptions, ctrl)
              "
              [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
            >
              {{ item.label }} {{ item.value }}
            </mat-checkbox>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
```

We use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dynamicForm.get(control.name) as ctrl">
```

to avoid repeat dynamicForm.get(control.name)

See that we use as [ngModel] -the're NO bannana sintax

```
[ngModel]="ctrl.value && ctrl.value.indexOf(item.value) >= 0"
```

To control, our update need as arguments

1. $event:true or false according is cheched or nor
2. item.value: the value of the option
3. control.checkboxOptions: the list of options
4. ctrl: the FormControl

The function update is very similar to when we have a component

```
  update(checked: boolean, value: string | number,options:any[],control:any) {
    const oldValue = control.value || [];
    if (!checked)
      control.setValue(
        oldValue.filter((x: string | number) => x != value)
      );
    else
      control.setValue(
        options
          .filter(
            (x: any) => x.value == value || oldValue.indexOf(x.value) >= 0
          )
          .map((x) => x.value)
      );
  }
```

But be carefull!!!

we only has an uniq FormControl

```
for (const control of this.controlsJson.controls) {
  if (control.type == 'checkboxgroup') {
      this.dynamicForm.addControl(
        control.name,new FormControl())
    }
  }
```

And we need take account when we define the "options", the "value" of each option should be diferent

```
 "checkboxOptions": [
      {
        "value": "false", //<--this value will be store
        "label": "Item 1",
        "name": "item1"
      },
      {
        "value": "true", //<--this value will be store
        "label": "Item 2",
        "name": "item2"
      }
    ],
```

If we want "at least one" only need add the Validators.required when we create the FormControl. Better we create a function that return an array of validators based in an array of string.

Imagine some like

```
"validators": ["required","max(3)"]
```

We can make a function

```
  getValidators(validators:string[])
  {
    return validators.map(x=>{
      if (x=="required")
        return Validators.required;
      if (x.substr(0,3)=="max")
      {
        const max=x.match(/max\((\d+)\)/)
        return Validators.max(+max[1])

      }
      ....
      return null //<--if some string not fullfilled any "if"
    }).filter(x=>x)
  }
```

And write some like

```
for (const control of this.controlsJson.controls) {
  if (control.type == 'checkboxgroup') {
      this.dynamicForm.addControl(
        control.name,new FormControl(null,this.getValidators(control.validators)))
    }
  }
```

See a [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-sjvc1x?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this. This was a good start... I didn't want to create a whole new component but i took the child component and put the code in the parent component. The form gets created form group correctly... but the browser created an error that                           Cannot find control with path: 'checkboxgroup1 -> item1'

Comment: @shine-dev, you're looping over formControl.controls. With your data the [control] should be "myForm.get('items')" not checkboxgroup1. BTW I imagine that the problem is that the "formControl.controls exist before you create the formGroup `myForm` (if is this only add to your form some like `<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]='myForm'...>` )

Comment: You might be right. Here's an implementation of what i'm witnessing...  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-uuimqq?file=app/app.module.ts  I'm not sure how to get around making sure the formGroup exists

Comment: I also put a name property for each of the checkbox options to be able to reference them later.

Comment: I got it... I was re-initializing the child formgroup unnecessarily... I've made changes to the forked demo... but also the final part is making sure the validator (minimum one selected works)

Comment: @shine-dev, I'm afraid you didn't understand me: It's an unique FormControl that store an Array. This FormControl can have a Validators.required. I forked your stackblitz and update the answer. I hope can help you. NOTE: Of course you can take another aproach that is create a FormGroup or a FormArray, (your stackblitz) but in this case remove the [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) they are unnecesary. In this another [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-qbn4z1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) I added a "AtLeastOne" validator

Comment: See that the "form" created are completly different

Comment: This is awesome! Appreciate it.