# How to validate multiple dynamic checkboxes in angular with formBuilder?

Tags: angular

I want to validate an array of checkboxes that are created dynamically in angular by using formBuilder. I want to have minimum of one checkbox checked to be valid.

I have a simple array of objects that is created dynamically (example data) in component.ts:

```
    movies: Book = [{title: 'titanic', year: 2013}, {title: 'matrix', year: 2002},];
    selectedMovies = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

    this.moviesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       movies: ['', Validators.required],
    )}
```

...and i have a *ngFor in my html template:

```
<div [formGroup]="moviesForm">
    <mat-checkbox
        *ngFor="let movie of movies"
        formControlName="movies"
        [checked]="selectedMovies.isSelected(movie)"
        (change)="selectedMovies.toggle(movie)"
    >
        <div>{{ movie.name }}</div>
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>`
```

When I select one checkbox, it makes form valid, but when I deselect checkbox, the form is still valid. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Why not use a [selection list](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists)?. BTW I wrote an answer if you want to do with mat-check-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mat-checkbox only have two values: true or false, so you need make "something" in order to assign the value to a FormControl.

One way is use the checked and change to change the value of the FormControl (but not use formControlName nor formControl in the mat-checkbox)

See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72941882/array-of-form-control-into-a-dynamic-formgroup/72951073#72951073)

Well if you want to store the whole object (you want the formControl value will be an array of objects instead of an array of numbers or an array of string) you can create two functions

```
  isChecked(item:any)
  {
    const value=this.form.get('control')?.value || [];
    return value.indexOf(item)>=0
  }
  update(checked: boolean, value: string | number) {
    const oldValue = this.form.get('control')?.value || [];
    if (!checked)
      this.form.get('control')?.setValue(
        oldValue.filter((x: string | number) => x != value)
      );
    else
      this.form.get('control')?.setValue(
        this.source
          .filter(
            (x: any) => x == value || oldValue.indexOf(x) >= 0
          )
      );
  }
```

And use some like

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of source">
    <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="isChecked(item)"
                  (ngModelChange)="update($event,item)">
      {{item.label}}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where

```
source:any=[
    {
      "value": 1,
      "label": "Item 1",
      "name": "item1"
    },
    {
      "value": 2,
      "label": "Item 2",
      "name": "item2"
    }
  ]
  form=new FormGroup({
    control:new FormControl([this.source[0]],Validators.required)

  })
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz8ebz-kuym4q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)
NOTE: From Angular 12 Validators.required is false when an array is empty